# arm v5(とv6)のandroidエミュレータを作るには？

Tags: android

arm v5(とv6)のandroid エミュレータを作成したいのですが、
sdk managerではarm v7のsystem imageしかダウンロード出来ないようです。
arm v5とv6のsystem imageは現在配布されていないのでしょうか？